# Как правильно применить метод ToUpper к списку C#

Tags: c#, list

```
 public class Method
{
   public List<Pepople> MetodToUpper (List<Pepople> list ) 
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.Name.ToUpper();
        }
       return list;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно создать метод, который бы делал из списка имен такой же список, но с верхним регистром. В примере тип списка - это класс, на это не нужно обращать внимание. Мне надо, что бы я в параметры метода в программе указал список в котором имена и он вернул бы мне новый список, но с большими буквами.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Код выше написали, ок, а дальше? Вот просто подумайте логически, что должно быть? У вас даже в вопросе есть ответ (`вернул бы мне новый список`). Ну и делайте значит новый список (`var result = new List<People>();`), а затем в него добавляйте копию объекта из `list` с измененным именем, будет вам в итоге такой метод.

Comment: `list.Select(item => item.Name.ToUpper()).ToList()`

Comment: Не работаю данный код. Буквы остаются с нижним регистром.                                                    
var People = new List<string>() { "Gleb", "Anton", "Egor"};

List<string> MetodToUpper(List<string> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        list.Select(item => item.ToUpper()).ToList();
    }
    return list;
}

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно советуют в комментариях.
Просто объединю это в одном ответе.

Вот пример кода, который выполняет необходимое вам действие:

```
    public List<Pepople> MetodToUpper(List<Pepople> list)
    {
        return list
            .Select(pepople => new Pepople
            {
                Name = pepople.Name.ToUpper()
                // ... маппинг остальных полей класса Pepople
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```